# Godot, playerData resource is missing before first save

Tags: game-development, godot, gdscript, godot4

In Godot4, I am trying to save and load a variable with resources. It seems to be missing as assigning first time before any save calls, gives a null reference and if saved once, it works properly. I am following a tutorial and maybe I am missing something.

playerData.gd:

```
extends Resource

class_name PlayerData

@export var health = 10

func change_health(value: int):
    health+=value
```

Main.gd:

```
extends Control

var save_file_path = "user://save/"
var save_file_name = "PlayerData.tres"

var playerData = PlayerData.new()


# Called when the node enters the scene tree for the first time.
func _ready():
    verify_save_dir(save_file_path)
    
    playerData = ResourceLoader.load(save_file_path+save_file_name).duplicate(true) # gives null at first time.
    
    if playerData:
        print(playerData.health)


func save_player_data():
    ResourceSaver.save(playerData, save_file_path + save_file_name)

func verify_save_dir(path : String):
    DirAccess.make_dir_absolute(path)
    
func _on_button_pressed():
    playerData.change_health(20)
    
    if playerData:
        print(playerData.health)
    

func _on_save_button_score_pressed():
    save_player_data()
```

Error:

> Cannot call method 'duplicate' on a null value.

What is the missing step?

Comment: incase, tut: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VGxYtJ3rXdE

Comment: workaround with `ResourceLoader.exists`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ResourceLoader.exists` to check if there player data to load.

Change this

```
playerData = ResourceLoader.load(save_file_path+save_file_name).duplicate(true) # gives null at first time.
```

to this:

```
if ResourceLoader.exists(save_file_path + save_file_name):
    playerData = ResourceLoader.load(save_file_path + save_file_name).duplicate(true)
```

It worked for me.